# How to populate List Items <li> from CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create/populate `<li>` from css file (instead of defining into HTML file).

**Cause/Target:**
I have different html files. All those files have menu, which designed as LIST `<li>`

Instead of entering one by one in all my html files I want to create/populate list items  within my CSS file. so that in future if have to add a single `<li>` then I would never have to edit my all html files one by one. Instead of that I would simple add one list item, so that it will be available into all my html files lists.

---EXISTING HTML CODE:

```
 <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a> </li>
      <li><a href="../about-us.html">About us</a> </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

---

I want `<li>` and `<a>` should be entered from CSS rather then into html file.

Comment: CSS is for styling only, you can't add elements to DOM using CSS. Use PHP or something other to process files.

Comment: CSS is for styling,HTML/XML/jSON can deal with your data..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript

```
<html>

<script>

   function buildList() {
      // prepare your variables
      var list = document.getElementById("list");
      var item01 = document.createElement("li");
      var item02 = document.createElement("li");

      // create list items
      item01.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item 01"));
      item02.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item 02"));

      // add list items to the list
      list.appendChild(item01);
      list.appendChild(item02);
   }

</script>

<body>

<ul id="list"></ul>

<script>
   // call function
   buildList();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Except you would want to put the script inside a separate javascript file and just call it everywhere you want to create your list